# How do I feed two mysql tables with one textarea?

Tags: php, html, mysql

This is my "Add Blog Post" page,
I want to remove one text area (the post description area) and then feed my mysql from the Post Content text area's content to both, the post description mysql field and the post content mysql field. How do I do that?
Code is attached below
In other words, I want to make my php script feed data from one text area to two mysql fields, the content is meant to be same, so I really don't need the other box but I am making some mistakes and cant get it working. . . I appreciate any help.

```
    <?php

    //if form has been submitted process it
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

        $_POST = array_map( 'stripslashes', $_POST );

        //collect form data
        extract($_POST);

        //very basic validation
        if($postTitle ==''){
            $error[] = 'Please enter the title.';
        }

        if($postDesc ==''){
            $error[] = 'Please enter the description.';
        }

        if($postCont ==''){
            $error[] = 'Please enter the content.';
        }

        if(!isset($error)){

            try {

                //insert into database
                $stmt = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO blog_posts (postTitle,postDesc,postCont,postDate) VALUES (:postTitle, :postDesc, :postCont, :postDate)') ;
                $stmt->execute(array(
                    ':postTitle' => $postTitle,
                    ':postDesc' => $postDesc,
                    ':postCont' => $postCont,
                    ':postDate' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
                ));

                //redirect to index page
                header('Location: index.php?action=added');
                exit;

            } catch(PDOException $e) {
                echo $e->getMessage();
            }

        }

    }

    //check for any errors
    if(isset($error)){
        foreach($error as $error){
            echo '<p class="error">'.$error.'</p>';
        }
    }
    ?>

    <form action='' method='post'>

        <p><label>Title</label><br />
        <input type='text' name='postTitle' value='<?php if(isset($error)){ echo $_POST['postTitle'];}?>'></p>

        <p><label>Description</label><br />
        
        
         <textarea name="postDesc" id="editor1" rows="10" cols="80">
              <?php if(isset($error)){ echo $_POST['postDesc'];}?>  This is my textarea to be replaced with CKEditor 4.
            </textarea>
            
        </p>

        <p><label>Content</label><br />
        
         <textarea name="postCont" id="editor1" rows="10" cols="80">
              <?php if(isset($error)){ echo $_POST['postCont'];}?>  This is my textarea to be replaced with CKEditor 4.
            </textarea>
        
        
        
    </p>

        <p><input type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit'></p>
         <script>
                // Replace the <textarea id="editor1"> with a CKEditor 4
                // instance, using default configuration.
                CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1' );
            </script>

    </form>

</div>
```

Comment: Simply issue another SQL insert statement using the data. Do it directly before/after your existing insert statement, but before your _header_ redirect.

Comment: please can you give an example or modify the code, I am a total newbie, using a tutorial based php simple blog script in HTML for my needs.

Comment: You've got one INSERT...next you'd need another one, same idea but different table. I think you could at least attempt that. But...why do you need to store the same data twice anyway? Normally that's a design flaw in a database

Comment: _please can you give an example_ - http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b1591924178a1ab61ca650f64d18f7891993bd3e

Answer (score 0):

Staying with precisely your original quetion, you could ignore the PostDesc form field, and use the content data twice as you insert the data. In your prepared statement, change SQL like this:

```
'INSERT INTO blog_posts (postTitle,postDesc,postCont,postDate) VALUES (:postTitle, :postCont, :postCont, :postDate)')
```

Then postCont would be inserted in both columns, postDesc and postCont.

That said, if you don't want postDesc, you could (should) cut back a lot of code: no description form field, no validation, no database insertion... No database field.